# do I need to install WSE 3 for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to add a service reference in VS 2010 (WCF). The web service uses WS-Policy and when I consume the service I get some commented code in my app.confing customBindings section:

```
<!--    WsdlImporter encountered unrecognized policy assertions in ServiceDescription 'http://ws.TheirSite.com/WebServices/ResellerApiV1.wsdl':    -->
<!--    <wsdl:binding name='ResellerApiBinding'>    -->
<!--        <ns0:SupportingTokens xmlns:ns0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">..</ns0:SupportingTokens>    -->
```

and I can't seem to create a SOAP header with the UserNameToken info.

Are these commented sections because I need to install WSE 3.0 or is that included with the 4.0 Framework?

**EDIT**: Thanks for the comments. The host got back to me and said I need to add this security tag to resolve this issue (*note the enableUnsecuredResponse is only available within the 4.0 Framework):

```
<security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" enableUnsecuredResponse="true" />
```

Apparently the commented xml in the app.config is caused by the VisualStudio WsdlImporter tool (svcutil.exe?) which can't process the SupportingTokens policy, but adding the above  directive will insert the WS-Security UsernameToken into the SOAP header.

Comment: WSE is obsolete. Do not use it unless you have no other choices at all. Your problem may be due to the fact that WSE does not implement the final WS-Policy standards (it was an interim product).

Comment: Ah-ha, thanks. I don't have it installed, and when I add the service reference I get that commented section of code in my app.config. Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: like I said, I bet those are obsolete policies which don't adhere to the standards.

Comment: Post your WSDL defining supporting token. Is it UserName with digested password?

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I've had to support WSE 3.0 in Visual Studio 2010 (not by choice) as we had some .NET 2.0 applications which (for a few reasons) we can't upgrade, and which need to use WSE 3.0 for some "non-standard" reasons.

You can have Visual Studio use the old Importer to generate WSDL proxies, but you need to install WSE 3.0 and make some modifications to configuration.  It's all documented in two blog posts here:

http://www.sanderstechnology.com/?p=10648

http://www.sanderstechnology.com/?p=10659

Answer (score 0):

Web Service Enhancements 3 (WSE 3) is not officially supported since Visual Studio 2008. The reason is that Microsoft wants you migrate your code to WCF.

Follow the blog below to enable WSE 3.0 in Visual Studio 2012, 2010 and 2008

http://digantakumar.com/2010/06/04/wse-3-in-visual-studio-2008-and-2010/